# How to scrape a website and all its directories from the one link?

Tags: python, web

Sorry if this is not a valid question, i personally feel it kind of boarders on the edge.

Assuming the website involved has given full permission
How could I download the ENTIRE contents (html) of that website using a python data scraper. By entire contents I refer to not only the current page you are on, but any other directory that branches off of that main website. Eg.

Using the link:

> https://www.dogs.com

could I pull info from:

> https://www.dogs.com/about-us

and any other directory attached to the "https://www.dogs.com/"
(I have no idea is dogs.com is a real website or not, just an example)

I have already made a scraper that will pull info from a certain link (nothing further than that), but I want to further improve it so I dont have to have heaps of links. I understand I can use an API but if this is possible I would rather this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while there is `scrapy` to do it professionally, you can use `requests` to get the `url` data, and `bs4` to parse the `html` and look into it. it's also easier to do for a beginner i guess.

anyhow you go, you need to have a starting point, then you just follow the link's in the page, and then link's within those pages.

you might need to check if the `url` is linking to another website or is still in the targeted website. find the pages one by one and `scrape` them.

Comment: So basically I need to search for links on the main page, then open those links and then scrape it? I am currently using bs4 in my scraper so how would I use bs4 to find links? Is there a certain "thing" or function that finds links?

Comment: look for <a> tag's and they are what you want. check if their `href` param is linking to other site or not, and then scrape the href.  yes `bs4` has methods to read parameters of tags in html. search or read the documents.

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I was looking for, appreciate the help my man!